# find the minimum value of $x^2-6x+9+ \dfrac{64}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

Looking for an elegant solution.

I can do by brute force, that is finding derivative and double derivative.

All Ideas will be appreciated and tried by me.

Comment: It might help that it is $(x-3)^2 + \left(\frac{8}{x}\right)^2$, but not sure how.

Comment: thats where it started from, I simplified

Comment: Maybe use the AM-GM mean inequality with what you started with?

Comment: The function is convex on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0, \infty)$ separately.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x=4+u$. Then it is easy to see
$$ x^2-6x+9+\dfrac{64}{x^2}=5+\frac{u^2(u^2+10u+28)}{(u+4)^2}=5+\frac{u^2[(u+5)^2+3]}{(u+4)^2}\ge 5 $$
and the equal sign holds if and only if $u=0$ or $x=4$. Thus the function reaches its min 5 when $x=4$.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but could you explain how you changed the expression in x to the one in u.  (I can see that they're equal, but I wouldn't have seen to write it this way.)

Comment: @user84413, this is the observation I got $x^4-6x^3+9x^2+64=(x-4)^2(x^2+2x+4)-5x^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I don't think I would have noticed this.